# Deleting a node from a simle linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

If I have these structs:

```
typedef struct item 
{
type data;
struct item *next;
} Item;
typedef struct list 
{
Item *head;
} List;
```

And a pointer to a node which I want to delete : `Item * toDelete`, which belongs to the list  `List lst`,
Can I use the following function to delete the node?:

```
void delete(Item * toDelete, List * lst){
   Item * tmp=lst->head;
   while (tmp->next!=toDelete){
       tmp=tmp->next;
   }
   tmp->next=toDelete->next;
   free(toDelete);
}
```

Or in other words, is it legal to compare between two pointers of structs?

Comment: If they are of same type it's legal. So, in your case it is legal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this function

```
void delete(Item * toDelete, List * lst){
   Item * tmp=lst->head;
   while (tmp->next!=toDelete){
       tmp=tmp->next;
   }
   tmp->next=toDelete->next;
   free(toDelete);
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because in the while loop there is no check whether `tmp` is equal to `NULL`. Secondly the function ignores the case when the node to be deleted is equal to the head node.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int delete( Item *toDelete, List *lst )
{
    Item **current = &lst->head;

    while ( *current && *current != toDelete )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    int success = *current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        *current = ( *current )->next;
        free( toDelete );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: So can I also write it like this?

`void delete(Item * toDelete, List * lst){`

  Item * tmp=lst->head;
   if (toDelete==lst->head){
        lst->head=lst->head->next;
        free(toDelete);
   }
   else{
        while (tmp&&tmp->next!=toDelete){
             tmp=tmp->next;
        }
  ` tmp->next=toDelete->next;`
   `free(toDelete);`
}